# What can't you express on the C langugage?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

I'm reading the spanish version of Modern Operating Systems 3rd edition, there's a section on Process Implementation that says

> "...Actions like saving registers and stablishing the stack pointer
>   cannot be expressed even in high level languages like C, instead they
>   are made with a small routine in Assembly..."

Can someone elaborate on this and give me an example of where the C language isn't enough to express something? Thanks.

EDIT: I want to know why you can't (according to the book) use the C language to write the ISR.

Comment: `saving registers and stablishing the stack pointer` is an example of where the C language isn't enough to express something.

Comment: Specifically, C, like most high-level languages, uses the stack and CPU registers "under the hood", hidden from the user, and thus does not give direct access to them.

Comment: @DoxyLover's analogy is a good one. You are sitting in the driver's seat of your car. How do you adjust the valve timing?  The user interface of a car usually gives you no control from the driver's seat that adjusts the valve timing; even in a car with VTEC there's no straightforward way to do so. Heck, if you're in an RX7 or a Tesla there might not be valves in the first place. Valve timing is an "under the hood" feature, not a "driver's seat" feature.

Comment: @DoxyLover, so you should use Assembly when you want a specific register to hold something, and C when you don't care which register holds it?

Comment: They're simply saying that C, like most HLLs, does not provide access to the actual registers and other mechanisms of the underlying hardware.  The only time you'd need this level of access would be if you were writing code in the operating system or in I/O drivers, etc.

Comment: Exactly. The job of the compiler is to decide when to enregister something based on the compiler's knowledge of the target hardware. If you could write a C program that said "this variable should go in EAX" then how would you be able to run that on an architecture that didn't have an EAX register? The point of C is that it gives you an abstraction that is higher than assembly.

Comment: In particular, an ISR must access registers (including "special purpose" ones) in the machine.  It also must manipulate the structures (stack, etc) that the C compiler assumes will be present when generated code executes.  I've done a few such things, in limited contexts, using a C-level language (PL/S), and while you can sometimes get away with it with a few tricks, you have to have intimate knowledge of *that* specific compiler and the way it does things, plus a bit of luck (and maybe some chutzpah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High level languages like C define a program to be working on an abstract machine. This abstract machine has no notion of different virtual address spaces, hardware interrupts, or process switching. Instead, it relies on such things as a stack to be set up.

Take for example the stack: Once the stack is set up correctly, the abstract machine can operate it, but there is no means in the abstract machine to say: "From now on, use this bit of memory as a stack, and start the stack pointer at this position." As such, at the very beginning of a program, a small snippet of assembler code is needed that sets the register which is used as a stack pointer to a sensible initial value. After that code snippet is run, it can hand over to code that uses the stack in the normal way.

One other thing that needs to be taken care of in assembler is interrupt handling: The hardware of your computer can signal to the CPU that it needs attention. The CPU responds to this by abandoning its current execution (this can happen between any two machine instructions!), and transfer execution to an interrupt handler. When this interrupt handler is entered, all the data the currently running process had in the CPU registers is still there and nowhere else. Worse, the interrupt handler typically has no idea what the program was actually intending to do with it. So the interrupt handler must save away all this state before it can do anything else, it would be impossible to resume the interrupted process if the interrupt handler failed to do this. This requires explicit access to *all* the registers, and a language that guarantees not to step on any unsaved state, so this must be done in assembler. Once the state is saved, control can be passed to routines written in C.

These are just two different examples of where and why assembler is needed even in modern systems. And I have not even touched on switching address spaces and the flushing TLBs that it requires...

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't make sense. Within C, you can only talk about things that C defines, and there's no such thing as "registers" or "stack" in C. If you're talking about some concrete piece of hardware, you can ask "which hardware operations does a C compiler use to implement C code", but that's a different and more specific question.